# addictive nickname for serverfault?

Tags: discussion, comments, stack-exchange

stackoverflow is crackoverflow

but crackfault doesn't have the same ring to it.  any suggestions?

Comment: How about *notmy* **fault**

Comment: brilliant! especially if you consider its the name that mark russinovich gave to an exe he wrote that crashes windows in fancy ways  http://download.sysinternals.com/Files/Notmyfault.zip

Comment: I'm pretty sure this exercise would be redundant with SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ServerFiend
- ServerFatty
- SalviaFault
- SkagFault
- SmackFault
- Spliffault

Answer (score 0):

How about:

- yourfault
- pusherfault

Comment: i thought yourfault was funnier

Comment: Yeah, but I missed the "addictive" part. Maybe I'll add it back.